# Disable internal keyboard in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, xinput, wayland

My laptop's <kbd>F1</kbd> key is being activated automatically , in Ubuntu 16.** I disabled the internal keyboard with
 - `xinput list`
 - get id of *At translated keyboard 2*: id=14
 - `xinput float 14`

But in the Ubuntu 17.10, `xinput list` doesn't list *At translated keyboard 2* any more.

What should I do to disable the internal keyboard?

Comment: can you post the output of `xinput list` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try disabling it via boot option
Open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as sudo .
Add i8042.nokbd,  to the end of the file, and save.